# PHP string has thousand Separators Multiplication

Tags: php

I have two strings. the one has a thousand separator as a comma, the other one has a decimal point as a dot.

below is my example code for explanation.

```php
$number1 = "250,000";
$number2 = "1.000";
```

what I want to do is to multiply those two strings. I somewhat found that PHP thinks the comma as a floating point!

```php
echo number_format($number1 , 3, ".", ",");

//result : 250.000 value type is still a string
```

I have already used the floatval() method but maybe i havn't used it in a proper way.

please can anyone help me with this problem? I want to multiply those two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this way

```
    $number1 = "250,000";
    $number2 = "1.000";

    $number1 = (float) str_replace(',', '', $number1);
    $number2 = (float) str_replace(',', '', $number2);

    $total = $number1 * $number2;
    echo  $total; // output => 250000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string manipulation like str_replace().

```
<?php

function parseFloatFromString($string)
{
    $string = str_replace(',', '', $string);
    $float = floatval($string);
    return $float;
}

echo parseFloatFromString("250,000") * parseFloatFromString("1.000");
```